# Segmentation fault C in writing a shell program

Tags: c, shell, unix

My code worked fine until I add the extra stuffs into it, like identifying and deal with cd,  >, <, >> and |. Could you please check my code and see where did the error happens? 
Btw the requirement of the assignment is only up to 1 pipe. And I think the problem starts somewhere from the for loop, cause I put printf right after it to check if it would print args[k], and it did but then the bug popped up and the program stopped.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
  const int MAX_ARGS = 10;
  char *token[MAX_ARGS + 1]; /*assume max number of token <=10*/
  char *temp;
  char line[256], command[MAX_ARGS];
  char prompt[] = "sh2 % ";
  pid_t pid;
  int i=0, j,k, status;

  printf("%s", prompt);

  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin) != NULL)
  {
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';    /*get rid of \n*/
    token[0] = strtok(line," ");
    strcpy(command,token[0]);    
    temp = strtok(NULL," ");
    while (temp != NULL)    
    {
      i = i+1;
      token[i] = temp;            
      temp = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    char *args[i+2];
    for (j = 0; j < (i+1); j++) 
    {
      args[j] = token[j];  
    }
    args[i+1] = NULL;

    if (!strcmp("exit",command))
      exit(0);
    if (!strcmp("cd", command))
    {
      int success;
      if (success = chdir(args[1]) <0)
      {
        printf("Failed to change dir.\n");
      }
    }
    else 
    {
      int piping = 0;
      int fd;
      for (k = 0; k < sizeof args; k++)
      {         
        if (!strcmp(">",args[k])) 
        {   
          fd = open(args[k+1],O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);
      if (fd <0) { printf("Open file failed.\n");}
          else 
      {
       dup2(fd, 1);
       args[k] = '\0';
       fflush(stdout);      
       close(fd);
      }
    }
    if (!strcmp("<", args[k]))
    {
      fd = open(args[k+1], O_RDONLY);
      if (fd <0) {printf("Open file failed.\n");}
      else
      {
        dup2(fd, 0);
        args[k] = '\0';
        close(fd);
      }
    }
    if (!strcmp(">>", args[k]))
    {
      fd = open(args[k+1], O_APPEND | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IXUSR);
      if (fd <0) {printf("Open file failed");}
      else
      {
            dup2(fd,1);
        args[k] = '\0';
        fflush(stdout);
        close(fd);
      }
    }
    if (!strcmp("|", args[k]))
    {
      piping = 1; 
        }
      } /*end for*/
      if (!(piping))
      {        
         pid = fork();
         if (pid <0) {}
         else if (pid == 0)
         {
           if ( (status = execvp(command, args)) < 0 )
       {
         printf("Command not found\n");
       }
         }
         else /*parent*/
         {
           wait(&status);          
         } /*end parent*/ 
      }/*end if not pipe*/
      else /*its pipe*/
      {
        int pfd[2];
    pipe(pfd);
    fd = fork();
    if (fd < 0) {}
    else if (fd ==0)
    {     
      close(pfd[1]);
      dup2(pfd[0],0);
      close(pfd[0]);
      execvp(args[2],args[2]);
    } 
    else /*parent*/
    {
      close(pfd[0]);
      dup2(pfd[1],1);
      close(pfd[1]);
      execvp(args[0],args[0]);
    }
      }/*end pipe*/
    } /*end outter else*/    

    printf("%s", prompt);

  }/*end  while*/
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: It simply said Segmentation fault, when I checked with a single command pwd

Comment: Your *debugger* segfaulted?

Comment: This loop: `for (k = 0; k < sizeof args; k++)` is most definitely wrong - `args` is an array of pointers, but you're iterating through its size in *bytes*.

Comment: Please tell us how exactly we can reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Compile your program with `-g -O0`, Run your program in `gdb`, and use the `bt` command to print a backtrace. That will tell you what is segfaulting.

Comment: And what did it indicate when you typed "backtrace" ? (assuming gdb here, but I don't think it is going to matter in the end).

Comment: FYI: `Compiler!= Debugger`

Comment: im running the program in unix. and as I just edited, the for loop should run at least once since it did print out the tokens as I tested.

Comment: Once again, run the program in `gdb` - that's a debugger. It runs in UNIX. It is not an alternative to UNIX. This will help you find the problem as well as stopping the world and his dog downvoting your post. If you can't find the problem, the results will also help us help you. Also, please indent your code properly (hint: `indent -nut - < yourfile.c | perl -p -i -e '{print "    ";}'` will give you something you can paste into Stack Overflow)

Comment: thanks for all your comments. I think I know where the bug is. I'm trying to fix it. It should be as cnicutar said that I refer to k+1 in the for loop, which will be null in cases none of the <,>,>> or | is found

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> for (k = 0; k < sizeof args; k++)
> ```

This is not how you iterate through `args`: this will go far beyond the end of the array. You want something like:

```
num = sizeof(args) / sizeof(*args);
for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
```

Alternatively, since you set the last element as `NULL`, you could do

```
for (char **arg = args; *arg; arg++)
```

Also note that you iterate with `k` until the end of the array and then use `k + 1`, which is very likely to cause problems.

Comment: @VictorN You really should heed the advice of people urging you to use  gdb or something. It has a bit of a learning curve but it can help a lot.